# How to store and access value from two spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

I'm new at programming and I'm learning Android dev with Kotlin.

I'm building a simple unit converter app.
There's two spinner (a dropdown) where user can select the original unit and the intended unit of conversion. Then there's a input field for user to indicate the value for conversion. Then if I press a button, I want the app to check the original and the intended unit then call the correct function to calculate conversion.

Here's my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A simple unit converter tool"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.059" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="From:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="To:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputField"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="key in value"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convert_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:text="Convert"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputField"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputField" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:text="Result:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/convert_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/convert_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:hint="converted value"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then this is my strings.xml code:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="Select_unit">Select unit</string>

    <string-array name="unit_list">
        <item>Inch</item>
        <item>Foot</item>
        <item>Yard</item>
        <item>Mile</item>
        <item>Pound</item>
        <item>Ounce</item>
        <item>Ton</item>
        <item>Celsius</item>
        <item>Fahrenheit</item>
        <item>Kelvin</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Lastly, this is the code that I have so far for the MainActivity.kt:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //constants. I will be using these to build my function later. 
    val inchToFoot = 0.083333
    val inchToYard = 0.027778
    val inchToMile = 0.000015783

    val footToInch = 12
    val footToYard = 0.333333
    val footToMile = 0.000189

    val yardToInch = 36
    val yardToFoot = 3
    val yardToMile = 0.000568

    val mileToInch = 63360
    val mileToFoot = 5280
    val mileToYard = 1760

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //declared button variable
        val buttonConvert: Button = findViewById(R.id.convert_button)

        //setup Spinner From
        val spinnerFrom: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.unit_list,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinnerFrom.adapter = adapter
        }

        //setup Spinner To
        val spinnerTo: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2)
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.unit_list,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinnerTo.adapter = adapter
        }


        spinnerFrom.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                //I wanted my button to access this variable but I don't know how
                val spinToTextFrom = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() 
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }

        spinnerFrom.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
               //I wanted my button to access this variable but I don't know how
               val spinToTextTo = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }

        //this is the button but I can't make it work as I don't know how to store the selected value from the two spinner
            
            buttonConvert.setOnClickListener {

            //logic to know which function to call
            if (spinnerFrom == "Inch" && spinnerTo.toString() == "Foot") {
                inchToFoot()

            } else if (spinnerFrom.toString() == "Inch" && spinnerTo.toString() == "Yard"){
                inchToYard()
            } else {
                inchToMile()
            }
        }
    }


    
    }
    
//List of functions I created, which I want the button to call base on the ifelse
    private fun inchToFoot() {
        val inputField: TextView = findViewById(R.id.inputField)
        val outField: TextView = findViewById(R.id.outputField)
        val cnvrtd: Double  = (inputField.text.toString().toDouble()) * inchToFoot
        val toStr: String = cnvrtd.toString()
        outField.setText("$toStr Foot")
    }

    private fun inchToYard() {
        val inputField: TextView = findViewById(R.id.inputField)
        val outField: TextView = findViewById(R.id.outputField)
        val cnvrtd: Double  = (inputField.text.toString().toDouble()) * inchToYard
        val toStr: String = cnvrtd.toString()
        outField.setText("$toStr Yard")
    }

    private fun inchToMile() {
        val inputField: TextView = findViewById(R.id.inputField)
        val outField: TextView = findViewById(R.id.outputField)
        val cnvrtd: Double  = (inputField.text.toString().toDouble()) * inchToMile
        val toStr: String = cnvrtd.toString()
        outField.setText("$toStr Mile")

    }
}
```

Comment: It's all good now. A friend of mine pointed out the issue on my spinner: